# Why my iOS app calendar return wrong day

Tags: ios, ios8, calendar

For 2015,July,3 it is Friday, but my app on some user's iphone devices just return Thursday,which is obviously wrong.

Just wonder why this happened ? How to fix it ?

Thanks,

Comment: They could be in a different timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need use NSDateFormatter to return the weekday for given date. In my case, the given date is converted to UTC, but didn't set the time zone as UTC, that will cause problem to display wrong weekday in some country with different time zone.

So the fixing solution is to set up the date formatter with correct time zone.

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") // my case date is UTC
```